# SQLite -- grouping data

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have the following query

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN cc.country IS NULL THEN dc.country ELSE cc.country END) AS Country,l.band FROM lotw l
 OUTER LEFT JOIN CountryCode cc on cc.code = l.dxcc
 OUTER LEFT JOIN DeleteCountry dc on dc.code = l.dxcc
 WHERE l.DXCC > ''  GROUP BY cc.Country,dc.country
```

Which produces the following results

```
Country                     Band

Bonaire                     15M
St. Maarten                 40M
Aland Is.                   20M
Alaska                      15M
Andorra                     80M
Antigua & Barbuda           10M
Argentina                   10M 
Aruba                       10M
Ascension Is.               20M
Asiatic Russia              40M
Austral I.                  40M
```

………

What I need is to get is a count of each band ?

```
  Band         Total
  10M           50 
  20M           20
  30M            5
```

So I tried this:

```
   select Band,Count(Band) FROM( 
     SELECT (CASE WHEN cc.country IS NULL THEN dc.country ELSE cc.country END) AS Country,
     l.band FROM lotw l
     OUTER LEFT JOIN CountryCode cc on cc.code = l.dxcc
     OUTER LEFT JOIN DeleteCountry dc on dc.code = l.dxcc
     WHERE l.DXCC > ''  GROUP BY cc.Country,dc.country
    )group by Band
```

This almost worked but the counts are off for example 10M the count should be 79 and its comes up 27?

however if I use this query and constrain to the 10M it works but I only get the one band :

```
select Band,Count(Band) FROM( 
 SELECT (CASE WHEN cc.country IS NULL THEN dc.country ELSE cc.country END) AS Country,
 l.band FROM lotw l
 OUTER LEFT JOIN CountryCode cc on cc.code = l.dxcc
 OUTER LEFT JOIN DeleteCountry dc on dc.code = l.dxcc
 WHERE l.DXCC > '' AND BAND = '10M' GROUP BY cc.Country,dc.country
)
```

Not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use COUNT(*) statement.
The following should work for the count column:

```
SELECT Band, COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM lotw l 
OUTER LEFT JOIN CountryCode cc ON cc.code = l.dxcc 
OUTER LEFT JOIN DeleteCountry dc ON dc.code = l.dxcc
WHERE l.DXCC > '' 
GROUP BY l.band
```

Here's a link on using Count(): http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: Hello AToya, Had already tried the count but again the count is off. Using the 10M as a example there should be 79 country used for 10M. when using the sql you supplied the numbers is 249 thanks for your reply

Comment: Would you mind sharing the tables and their column names? I'm curious with the two OUTER LEFT JOINs. I believe that is where your problem lies, not with the COUNT statement.

Comment: sure how would you like me to share them?

Comment: I would just like to know the table names with their corresponding values. For instance, Table: Country Code (ID, Name, Code, etc.)

Comment: CountyCode: Id, prefix,Cont,ITU,CQ,Code,flags, deletecountry:CountyCode: Id, prefix,Cont,ITU,CQ,Code,flags

Comment: lotw: id,call,band,mode,dxcc

Comment: lotw.dxcc represents a country. both country tables have the country in the with their corresponding country countrycode.code hope this helps

Comment: Try grouping by Band, CC.Country, and DC.Country.

GROUP BY BAND, cc.Country, dc.Country